# Navigation image-link not working

Tags: hyperlink

This should be simple but I can't figure out why this image-link doesn't work? When I hover over the image it's as though there isn't a link to click on but it's there...see code below.

```
.researchnav {
display: block;
background: url(../images/research.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 457px;
height: 38px;
margin-left: 370px;
text-indent: -9999px;
```

}

```
.researchnav:hover {
display: block;
background: url(../images/research_over.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 457px;
height: 38px;
margin-left: 370px;
```

}

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="researchnav"><a href="research.html">Research</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I figured it out! In the css it should be .researchnav a  : )

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the styles to the **a** instead of the **li**.

```
<a class="researchnav" href="research.html">Research</a>
```

Comment: Hello, I tried that but unfortunately that doesn't work either. Thank you.